# Why doesn't "heroku logs --app my-app" show my logs?

Tags: logging, heroku

When I type `heroku logs --app my-app-staging` I see the logs for my staging app.  When I type `heroku logs --app my-app-production`, I don't see anything.  But when I type `heroku logs -t --app my-app-production`, I'm able to tail my production logs with no issue.  Additionally, the log drain that I've set up is shipping no data.

We're using these addons: Librato, Logentries, and FlyData.  I suspect that one of them may be blocking standard log gathering, but I can't figure out which one it might be.

Has anybody else run in to this?  Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two-part answer:
1. I messed up the logstash instance that was supposed to accept data from the drain.  So the drain was working fine, I just messed up other stuff.
2. If you're generating more than 2000 log entries per second, Heroku will not show you your logs.  Good to know.